# Decode string with %CC%88 -encoding with PHP?

Tags: php, excel, decode

Dear stackoverflow'ers,

I have this problem that drives me absolutely crazy. I hope that some genius (or just a normal person) can help my find an answer.

What do I want?

1. With Excel, I send a string (a file path) to a php-file
2. The PHP file GET's the path
3. The PHP file echo's the path

The path is the following: `Financiën/file.xls` (notice the ë)

But when I echo the path it gives `Financie%CC%88n/file.xls`).

I know it is some sort of conversion (it means the e should be combined with ¨), but HOW do I DEcode it with php to normal utf8?!?!

I searched all the internet, but I don't know how to find the right answer :s

Who is my hero?! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want [`urldecode($path);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Set your document encoding if you're sending the decoded string to the browser as HTML, like:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

For text mode set the correct headers first:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Hi! I tried that, but that didn't work: when I do I get: "FinancieÌˆn/file.xls". Also strange...

Comment: Hey, that is strange! When I type "echo urldecode('Financie%CC%88n/file.xls')" in codepad it spits out the correct "Financiën", but when I copy the EXACT same code from codepad to my own php file on the server it gives me "FinancieÌˆn". How is that possible? (we're getting closer though...)

Comment: Did you read my edit? Add that meta tag in your `<head>` part of your page

Comment: YES! That was problem 1! Very good, thank you very much! There is only one more thing... For the rest of the code, I need to get the following code to output 'true': if($path=="Financiën/file.xls"){echo "true";}   This is not the case right now, even if I uncode it first. Why is that? (thanks for your help again..)

Comment: I have found more info: when I put the utf8 metatag above the page, the text looks good. But I need to have two php var's that match ($path1 and $path2), from which I have influence on only one of them. The ë-character I have to match looks, when I remove the utf8 metatag, like this: Ã« But the ë character from the string I have urldecoded as instructed above, looks like eÌˆ when the metatag is removed. So I need this last one to match the first one with php (and not by metatag). How can I do this?

Comment: It seems that the characters are different, even though they look the same. Did you try to copy-paste the decoded string from the browser and put that in your condition?

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't work because it is a different kind of utf-8. Found out the only solution would be to normalize it. Unfortunately I cannot use Normalize on my shared hosting environment, so I think I have to give up and except I cannot use too strange characters... :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem here with "u%CC%88". The original letter is a normal german "Umlaut" "ü". The "%CC%88" seems only to be the dots above the "u". When you try to rename a file with this "u%CC%88" in its name with windows 7 explorer, set the cursor behind the 'ü' and delete to the left, then the 'u' is left over.

Watch out, that no program generates such characters, it should generate the normal UTF-8 "ü" or in your case the normal UTF-8 "ë".

Even if you set your HTML to

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

HTML validator tells you

> Text run is not in Unicode Normalization Form C.